# Blender Google Colab "Failed to create CUDA context (Unknown error)" error

Tags: rendering, gpu, error

I tried rendering an image on google colab but I always get an error saying "Failed to create CUDA context (Unknown error)".It works fine when I change the render settings in blender to cpu but its super slow.

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Thanks.